# How to extract date and time from SAS Datetime25.6 format under a data step?

Tags: datetime, sas

Say i have a column known as 'Date' from a dataset xyz, where values are in a datetime25.6 format, how do I extract date in a mm/dd/yyy format and time in a hh:mm:ss format under a data step? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the `date` column a character containing a datetime representation or number (datetime value in column with a datetime format)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
data test;
   dt = '30oct2023 11:13:00'dt;
   d  = datepart(dt);
   t  = timepart(dt);
   format dt datetime25.6 d mmddyy10. t time8.;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that SAS dates and datetimes are stored as number of days or seconds since midnight 01JAN1960.

Considering your question, if the value for your datetime is formatted with a datetime25.6 format, we might assume that you have it stored as a SAS datetime and that it appears like: 30OCT2023:17:22:21.729397, due to the format you may have applied. If that's the case though, it's likely stored internally as something like: 2014307370.1 (again, the seconds since midnight, 01JAN1960). You could create that scenario with:

```
data xyz;
    date = datetime();
    format date datetime25.6;
    output;
run;

Result: 30OCT2023:17:45:07.645031
```

If you want to use the value as a character literal you can apply the SAS put function to convert it to a character string to represent the same datetime:

```
data want;
    set xyz;
    date_char = put(date, datetime25.6);
run;

Result: 30OCT2023:17:45:07.645031
```

The result looks the same, but the key is that the first is the mathematical representation with a format applied and the second is the same, but cast to a character string. Both are useful and appropriate. But the latter can be used as a numerical value for calculations as is often required. If that fits your needs, keep it as a numerical value and use the format as a way to visualize without giving up the mathematical properties that the numerical value affords you. You can always apply a format after the fact in listings, tables and other reports without changing the underlying value.